# Variable scope in vue view

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I achieve something like the following in Vue? Psuedo code:

```
<div v-context="getPerson(id)">
   <p>Name: {{ $data.name }}</p>
   <p>Age: {{ $data.age }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not create a new component 'Person' and pass the 'person' as a prop?

Comment: @M.Suurland Yeah, but can I do that inline with a `template` tag or something? Or do I have to create a `person.vue`?

Comment: Ye, something like this: <person :person="voo.person"></person>, next create a person.vue and access the name and age here.

Comment: Out of the box, Vue doesn't support variable scope. There might be some way you could do this with a [custom directive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're returning an object, so you can actual take that method and use `v-for` to iterate through, like so:

```
<div>
   <p v-for=" (val, key) in getPerson(id)">{{key}}: {{val}}</p>
</div>
```

The documentation has more info: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-v-for

Comment: What I'm looking for is a scoped variable. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: you can do like `getPerson(id).name` or `getPerson(id).age`